# Working with Precise Decimals

Tags: java, percentage

Im trying to work with a form that creates a precise decimal from two JTextareas into a 3rd JTextarea.

Eg

Produced Goods --------  32746534

Spoiled Goods --------       4756

Spoiled Percentage ------  xx.xxxxxxxx%

It needs to be exact and work with 11 digit produced goods and 10 decimal point percentages.

.

```
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(linerInfeedTextField.getText()));
                BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(shellsSPoiledTextField.getText()));

                BigDecimal d3 = d1.multiply(d2); // d1 + d2 is invalid
                BigDecimal d4 = d3.divide(new BigDecimal(100));

                percentSpoiledTextField.setText(d4+"%");
```

Comment: If understand you right you could try using DecimalFormat
Example: 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.########");
df.format(d2);
...

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Im trying to figure out how to calculate precisely. its calculating completely wrong. Seems to be rounding off wrong. I think i have the wrong data type.

Comment: I think you haven't defined your terms. For example, 'wrongly'. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with your choice of data type.

Comment: Should have been Using DecimalFormat instead of BigDecimal. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DecimalFormat..

**Example:**

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.####") // <- "###.###" specifies precision

double x = 143.13;
double y = 23.12;
double answer = x / y;

System.out.println("Answer: " + df.format(answer));
```

Comment: You can adjust precision by manipulating DecimalFormat constructor #.#### -> 1.0000 , #.## -> 1.00 e.c.

Comment: Thats perfect. Just need to multiply the answer by 100 to get %.